# How to add "Last Position" button to my tool bar in VB6 IDE

Tags: vb6

I did this before but can't remember how the heck I did it.

I want to have a button on my vb6 IDE toolbar that takes me back to the previous place I was in the code (in my "history) -- an incredibly useful feature.

I have it in my properties (right-click) menu but don't see it in the other menus from which I could drag it to the Toolbar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

1. In the IDE right click an empty spot on your
   menu and select *Customize...*
2. Select the *Command*  tab in the Customize dialog
3. Select *View*  from the *Categories* list.
4. On the *Commands* list you should see
   an item called *Last Position*. 
   Drag this item to a toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for this, no more putting 'qwertyuiop comments in my code for me!

Answer (score 7):

@Jay's answer is right on.  There are also handy shortcut keys for this feature and the related Definition feature:

- Last Position:  <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Definition: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In one of the toolbars in the sample applications?